# Regex.Replace not working as expected with Regexoptions.IgnoreCase

Tags: c#, .net, regex

If I have a few strings:

```
str = "This is a cool string (orch. details here): 2. Denied."
str2 = " (Orch. details here)" <--notice the capital letter
```

and then I do this line of code to try to clear that part out:

```
str3 = Regex.Replace(str, str2, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

`str3` ends up being exactly as what `str` was before execution. I suspect that it is not "seeing" the other characters such as the periods because when I do this with just simple alphabetic characters in `str` and `str2` then it will replace it just fine.

What gives?! :)

Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both parens and periods have meanings in regular expressions.  Hence it's not trying to literally match the contents of `str2` but instead a regular expression that is defined by `str2`.  If you want it to match literally you need to escape the string

```
str2 = Regex.Escape(str2);
```

Comment: JaredPar, thank you so much, man! That worked like a charm. I am going to go research it now.